# Opencv step for Triangulate point from stereo image

Tags: python, image, opencv, point, triangulation

I'm trying to triangulate points from stereo images.On the web I find a lot of confusion, because there are many different methods.

I have two images of the same subject in different angles, with manually defined landmarks,(for example , 2 faces where I scored 3 points: nose and pupils).

I would like to go back to the three-dimensional position of these points through their triangulation.

It could be listed the various steps to be performed to get this result in OpenCv for python?

Comment: Is the angle from which the two photos were taken known to you?

Comment: no .. I do not know the angle

Answer (score 0):

To triangulate you need to now position of cameras.
Those position can be presented in different forms, translate, rotation, or affine, depend of needs.

Construct two rays from each camera thru the same landmark.
In theory find intersection of those two rays.
In practice find point that is closest to both rays.
That point is what you want.